# Shifting properties through a string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css

What I'm trying to do is create a paragraph of text, apply a CSS property to it, then shift that property throughout the string in, for example, 500ms increments.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("p").css("color","red");
});
```

Let's say I have 200 words in my paragraph, could I have that CSS apply to only one word at a time, shifting incrementally from 0 to 199 in the string? Making one word red, then the next, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it this way, by adding class (you can also add some transitions in there via css):

```js
var p = $('.highlight-words')
var words = p.text().split(' ');
var toAppend = [];
$.each(words, function(i, v) {
    toAppend.push( '<span>' + v + '</span>' );
});
p.html( toAppend.join(' ') );
var spans = p.find('span');
function delayClass( elem, delay ) {
 setTimeout(function() {
     elem.prev().removeClass( 'highlighted' );
     elem.addClass( 'highlighted' );
    }, delay);
};
var delay = 0;
spans.each(function(i, span) {
 delayClass( $(span), delay );
    delay += 500;
});
```

```css
.highlighted {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="highlight-words">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kqLtfdrw/1/).

Comment: You take the contents as `.text()`, but re-set it as `.html()`. This would cause an HTML-like expressions in the text to be interpreted, potentially creating a security issue.

Comment: It has to be set via `.html()` cause we have spans inside. What the security issue may ever happen here, `.text()` already removes any HTML-like expressions anyway?